# Intersection of ideals is an ideal in Lie algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

I'm working through a Lie Algebra textbook by myself and running into some problems. I'm aware this is a probably a simple question but I've never gone through a math textbook by myself and I've not done much Linear Algebra.

The question is proving that if $I$ and $J$ are ideals of $L$, the Lie algebra, then prove $I\cap J$ is also an ideal. Now the book says that we only need to show that if $x\in L$ and $y\in I\cap J$ then $[x,y]\in I\cap J$ since we should know that $I\cap J$ is a linear subspace of $L$.

Question 1: Is $I\cap J$ a subspace of $L$ since $I$ and $J$ are already ideals (and therefore subspaces) of $L$ so then automatically $I\cap J$ is a subspace of $L$?

Question 2: Do we prove that $[x,y]\in I\cap J$ the same way you would for a commutative ring? As in since $I$ and $J$ are ideals then by definition $xy \in I$ and $xy\in J$ therefore $xy\in I\cap J$ ie $[x,y]\in I\cap J$? Or am just making up math :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer 1: Yes, that is correct.

Answer 2: It's the same thing for any kind of algebra. In this case, if $x\in L$ and if $y\in I\cap J$, then $[x,y]\in I$ (since $x\in L$, $y\in I$ and $I$ is an ideal of $L$) and $[x,y]\in J$ (since $x\in L$, $y\in J$ and $J$ is an ideal of $L$). Therefore, $[x,y]\in I\cap J$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.